# Детерминированный автомат на Java

Tags: java, конечные-автоматы

Здравствуйте! Очень стыдно обращаться сюда с такими вопросами, но любопытство побеждает. Недавно пытался пройти собеседование на обучение и не прошел, но интерес к задаче остался. Задача: на вход через консоль поочередно подаются 0 и 1. Программа выводит в консоль Yes, если поступило чётное количество 0 и нечётное 1, в остальных случаях в консоль выводится No. Собственно вот [**КОД**](https://github.com/ElNobel/Repository/tree/master/FSM/src), который я написал. Естественно не правильная реализация КА.

Comment: Добро пожаловать на StackOverflow на русском. **1.** В чем именно состоит ваш вопрос? **2.** Если у вас проблема с кодом - у нас принято прикладывать минимальный восппроизводимый пример непосредственно в вопрос.

Comment: Извините, в следующий раз постараюсь именно так и сделать, но тут случай был таков что пришлось сделать ссылку на репозиторий своего кода, поскольку в моём коде не было ошибки он не отражал суть задания, а выкладывать сюда полный код заняло бы слишком много места

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(Сразу оговорюсь, что профильного образования у меня нет, и терминология страдает)

Конечный автомат сам по себе не хранит историю операций с ним, это просто набор состояний с правилами перехода из одного в другое, и в определенный момент времени автомат представлен просто одним состоянием. Ваше решение (скорее всего) не подошло, потому что вы использовали логику для вычислений и построили вычислитель вместо реализации непосредственно автомата.

От вас, скорее всего, хотели автомат с четырьмя состояниями:

- Получено четное число нулей, четное число единиц
- Получено нечетное число нулей, четное число единиц
- Получено четное число нулей, нечетное число единиц
- Получено нечетное число нулей, нечетное число единиц

Или еще проще:

```
состояние = (четное/нечетное количество нулей, четное/нечетное количество единиц) = (bool, bool)
```

В этом случае явно можно определить переходы между состояниями

```
(четное, четное) -> получена единица -> (четное, нечетное)
```

Разница в финальном результате отсутствует, но вот сам автомат при этом начинает существовать в виде отдельной единицы и выполнять свои конкретные функции. Остается только реализовать его, в связи с простотой логики не обязательно описывать переходы:

```
public class FiniteStateMachine {

    private boolean evenAmountOfZerosProcessed = true;
    private boolean evenAmountOfOnesProcessed = true;

    public void accept(int nextNumber) {
        switch (nextNumber) {
            case 0:
                evenAmountOfZerosProcessed = !evenAmountOfZerosProcessed;
                break;
            case 1:
                evenAmountOfOnesProcessed = !evenAmountOfOnesProcessed;
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected input: " + nextNumber);
        }
    }

    public State getState() {
        if (evenAmountOfZerosProcessed && !evenAmountOfOnesProcessed) {
            return State.CORRECT;
        }
        return State.INVALID;
    }

    enum State {
        CORRECT,
        INVALID
    }
}
```

По-хорошему состояния и возможные переходы должны быть выражены отдельным enum, но, скорее всего, вышеприведенной реализации было бы достаточно.

Comment: Все правильно написано, добавлю только пояснение. Конечный автомат потому и называется конечным - что у него **конечное число состояний**. В данном случае - 4. А автомат автора вопроса имел (в теории) бесконечное число состояний, поскольку поля `numberOfZero` и `numberOfOne` могут расти неограниченно.

Comment: Кстати, КА в Java удобно делать через абстрактные перечисления (Enum).

Comment: Спасибо большое! Буду разбирать код))

Comment: Простите пожалуйста может я по неопытности не могу найти различия в вашем примере и моим примером. Будьте добры подскажите в чем я был не прав?

Comment: @НикитаТитов я писал, что входные-выходные условия у нас одинаковые, а сама разница в концепции. КА - это набор состояний, переходов и правил этих переходов (и ничего больше), у вас получился аккумулятор, который подсчитывает состояние и сам по себе автоматом не является (точнее, является, но в вышеприведенной формулировке Павла), который, к тому же, напрямую что-то читает (он этого делать не должен). Автомат в текущем состоянии - это именно кортеж из (нечетность обработанного количества единиц, четность обработанного количества нулей), и ничего больше.